# Как проверить подзапрос на пустоту в oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql-developer

Собственно, схема запроса примерно такая:

```
SELECT <столбцы>
FROM <таблица>
WHERE <столбец_1> NOT IN
    (<подзапрос>)
```

Смысл вопроса в том, что если <подзапрос> дал пустую выборку, то строку не следует выводить. Но NOT IN даст положительный ответ, т.к. <столбец_1> отсутствует в пустой выборке, поэтому строка будет выведена (а мы этого не хотим). Как добавить проверку на пустоту в таком случае?

Comment: Использовать `NOT EXISTS` вместо `NOT IN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй оператор EXISTS.
*Если подзапрос возвращает хотя бы одну запись в результирующем наборе, то условие EXISTS будет определяться как TRUE (истина), и условие EXISTS будет выполнено*

```
SELECT mytab_1, mytab_2 FROM mytable_1 t1 WHERE 
     EXISTS (SELECT*FROM mytable_2 t2 WHERE t1.mytab_1 = t2.mytab_1)
```

http://oracleplsql.ru/exists.html

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, если рассуждать в контексте моего вопроса?
SELECT <столбцы>
FROM <таблица> T
WHERE <столбец_1> NOT EXISTS
    (<подзапрос>
    AND <подзапрос>.<столбец_1> = T.<столбец_1>)

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов без столбца, просто `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: Да, уже заметил косяк. Вроде бы работает, хммм.